# How to create Jmeter script where Admin approves user registration request and grab e-mail registration URL by excluding the Admin approval

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, ruby-jmeter

1. User URL: User registers to website and wait for confirmation e-mail.
2. Admin approves the  user request from back end of the application and confirmation e-mail is send to user e-mail id
3. User login to e-mail account and clicks on registration URL to register.

I want to record a jmeter script where Admin approving  the user request from back end (Step 2) should be excluded but at the same time user should be approved and complete registration.

How to record a test script with above condition in Jmeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current JMeter version is capable of recording HTTP and HTTPS requests only.

In order to implement step 2 you will need to read user's mailbox with [Mail Reader Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler), extract registration confirmation link with i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), store it into a JMeter Variable and re-use in in your Step 3.

I believe that [How to Create a JMeter Script to Check Email During Registration AND Grab the Confirmation URL](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-create-jmeter-script-check-email-during-registration-and-grab-confirmation-url) guide provides good step-by-step walkthrough.